# How to render to texture in Vulkan?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I need render to textrue in my project.

Pass1 : Draw a color square that color is (0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0) and render target is a texture.

Pass2 : Draw a textured square that use pass1's texture and render target is a surface.

Expected result:

[image]

But I got strange result as follow:

[image]

Create image using the following:

```
  VkImage hImageTexture = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
  VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = {0};
  imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
  imageCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
  imageCreateInfo.flags = 0;
  imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
  imageCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
  imageCreateInfo.extent.width = width;
  imageCreateInfo.extent.height = height;
  imageCreateInfo.extent.depth = 1;
  imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 1;
  imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
  imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
  imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
  imageCreateInfo.usage =
    VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT |
    VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT |
    VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
  imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
  imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
  imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
  imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
  //
  VkResult res = vkCreateImage(hDevice , &imageCreateInfo , nullptr , &hImageTexture);
```

Create image view using the following:

```
  VkImageView hImageViewTexture = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
  VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo = {0};
  imageViewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
  imageViewCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
  imageViewCreateInfo.flags = 0;
  imageViewCreateInfo.image = hImageTexture;
  imageViewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
  imageViewCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
  imageViewCreateInfo.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R;
  imageViewCreateInfo.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G;
  imageViewCreateInfo.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B;
  imageViewCreateInfo.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A;
  imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
  imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
  imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
  imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
  imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
  VkResult res=vkCreateImageView(
    hDevice,
    &imageViewCreateInfo,
    NULL,
    &hImageViewTexture);
```

Render loop as follows:

```
  //Pass1
  //Clear texture  color
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier();//Transition layout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
  vkCmdClearColorImage();//Clear color(0.0 , 0.0 ,0.0 , 1.0)
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier();//Transition layout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL
  //Change texture's barrier
  VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrierForOutput = {0};
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.pNext = nullptr;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.srcAccessMask = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.dstAccessMask = 
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.image = hImageTexture;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForOutput.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    hCommandBuffer,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT,
    0,
    0,
    nullptr,
    0,
    nullptr,
    1,
    &imageMemoryBarrierForOutput);
  //draw
  vkCmdBeginRenderPass();
  vkCmdSetViewport();
  vkCmdSetScissor();
  vkCmdBindPipeline();
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets();
  vkCmdBindVertexBuffers();
  vkCmdBindIndexBuffer();
  vkCmdDrawIndexed();
  vkCmdEndRenderPass();
  //
  //Pass2
  //Clear surface color
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier();//Transition layout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
  vkCmdClearColorImage();//Clear color(0.5 , 0.5 ,1.0 , 1.0)
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier();//Transition layout to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL
  //Change texture's barrier
  VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrierForInput = {0};
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.pNext = nullptr;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.srcAccessMask = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.dstAccessMask = 
    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT |
    VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.image = hImageTexture;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
  imageMemoryBarrierForInput.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
  vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    hCommandBuffer,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT,
    0,
    0,
    nullptr,
    0,
    nullptr,
    1,
    &imageMemoryBarrierForInput);
  //draw
  vkCmdBeginRenderPass();
  vkCmdSetViewport();
  vkCmdSetScissor();
  vkCmdBindPipeline();
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets();
  vkCmdBindVertexBuffers();
  vkCmdBindIndexBuffer();
  vkCmdDrawIndexed();
  vkCmdEndRenderPass();
```

Pass1 vertex shader:

```
#version 450

layout (location=0) in vec4 inPos;
layout (location=0) out vec4 outPos;

void main(void)
{
  outPos = float4(inPos.xy , 0.0 , 1.0);  
  gl_Position = outPos;
}
```

Pass1 fragment shader:

```
#version 450

layout (location=0) in vec4 inPos;
layout (location=0) out vec4 outColor;

void main(void)
{
  outColor = float4(0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 1.0);    
}
```

Pass2 vertex shader:

```
#version 450

layout (location=0) in vec4 inPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 inUV;
//
layout (location=0) out vec4 outPos;
layout (location=1) out vec2 outUV;
//
void main(void)
{
  outPos = inPos;
  outUV = inUV;
  //
  gl_Position=outPos;
}
```

Pass2 fragment shader:

```
#version 450
//
layout (location=0) in vec4 inPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 inUV;
//
layout (binding=1) uniform sampler2D inTex;
layout (location=0) out vec4 outColor;
void main(void)
{
  outColor = texture(inTex , inUV);
}
```

If I change image tiling to `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` then I get the following:

[image]

If change image tiling to `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` without clear(pass1's clear), the result was correct!

What mistakes have I made?

**EDIT:**
I add some code that how i change texture's barrier in render loop .

**EDIT:**
I set dependency when create render pass as follow

```
  VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency[2];
  subpassDependency[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
  subpassDependency[0].dstSubpass = 0;
  subpassDependency[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
  subpassDependency[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
  subpassDependency[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
  subpassDependency[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
  subpassDependency[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
  //
  subpassDependency[1].srcSubpass = 0;
  subpassDependency[1].dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
  subpassDependency[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
  subpassDependency[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
  subpassDependency[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
  subpassDependency[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
  subpassDependency[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
```

but nothing to changed.

Comment: You have a dependency: the second pass depends on the first. What synchronization methods are you doing?

Comment: Why are you constantly clearing the image outside of the renderpass? Just let `loadOp` do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer.May be i know what i make a mistake,I should be use two subpass in one renderpass.Render pass is parallel executed that can explained why 
 got strange result.

Comment: You don't need to do them as two subpasses in the same renderpass, though I think that would work for what you're doing. But you need synchronization between renderpasses: the artifacts you're seeing suggest that some parts of the second pass are running before the first pass is complete. I'd take a look at the pipeline barriers between the two renderpasses: they need pipeline stage and access masks that ensure ordering and cache coherence.

Comment: Thanks for answer.vkCmdPipelineBarrier() let me confused that why it can synchronization.Is i set wrong pipeline stage mask?

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a graphics-graphics dependency on the first pass output color attachment.
The second subpass shader read operations have to wait for the first subpass color attachment writing operations to be done.

```cpp
 VkSubpassDependency deps[...];
  //other values to handle external dependencies
  ...
  // the src operations will refer to the first subpass
  deps[0].srcSubpass = 0; 
  // the dst operations will refer to the second subpass 
  deps[0].dstSubpass = 1;
  // the operations from the first subpass that will have to be completed
  // the writes to the color attachment in the color attachment output stage 
  deps[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
  deps[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
  // this operations will wait on those specified in the previous lines
  // the reads issued during the fragment shader will have to wait 
  // until all the writes have been completed 
  deps[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
  deps[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
  // do not wait for every write to have finished
  // if all writes in a region have been completed
  // then the reads can start (only in that region) 
  deps[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
```

This takes care of the synchronization between the subpasses and the changes of layout *in one frame* as the subpasses specify the layouts of the attachments.
Then you need to signal to the pipeline that you intend to move to the next render pass.

```cpp
  //draw
  vkCmdBeginRenderPass();

  vkCmdSetViewport();
  vkCmdSetScissor();
  vkCmdBindPipeline();
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets();
  vkCmdBindVertexBuffers();
  vkCmdBindIndexBuffer();
  vkCmdDrawIndexed();
  
  vkNextSubpass();
  
  vkCmdSetViewport();
  vkCmdSetScissor();
  vkCmdBindPipeline();
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets();
  vkCmdBindVertexBuffers();
  vkCmdBindIndexBuffer();
  vkCmdDrawIndexed();

  vkCmdEndRenderPass();
```

For examples of common synchronization operations you can check out the [vulkan synchronization examples page](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples-(Legacy-synchronization-APIs)).
Your problem is *First draw writes to a color attachment. Second draw reads from it as an input attachment in the fragment shader* as you are doing everything in one render pass by dividing it in more subpasses.

Answer (score 0):

The comments here suggest using pipeline barriers, but I can't immediately see an error with your usage.  Two ways to help you diagnose this problem:

1. Add the debug utils layer.  If you haven't got this layer enabled, then you are partially in the dark because you won't get the error reports you need.  The debug layer is essential for diagnosing errors: https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_EXT_debug_utils.html
2. Install Nsight Graphics, and capture your application.
   You can step through every draw call, look at the graphics state, and examine your render targets.  You may even get an error which points you to the problem.  Using a debugger like this will save you a lot of time when developing Vulkan code.  https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics